# How OpenVPN etc create VPN connection if there is no Android API for that?

Tags: android, vpn, openvpn

There are many answers on SO already claiming that you cannot programmatically configure a VPN profile on Android device. The VpnService API from Android only allows usage of VPN in your own app, and there is no other API available.

The how do apps like OpenVPN for Android etc. achieve that? I can configure profile through the OpenVPN app and other apps will be able to use this connection.

Comment: Why do you think the VpnService API limits the VPN to a single app?

Comment: Because using VPNService only gives back the handle of the connection where you can send/receive packets. Other apps do not have access to this handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the nature and purpose of the handle/file descriptor returned by `VpnService.Builder`'s [`establish()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder.html#establish()) method. You might want to read the API description again.

The gist of it is that it's a file descriptor for a TUN device to which Android directs network traffic from other apps via policy routing (affected apps/traffic can be controlled through the methods of the builder). The app can then use the file descriptor to read the packets sent by other apps and e.g. forward them through a VPN connection (using a regular UDP/TCP socket). Returning traffic from a VPN connection can likewise be re-injected into the system by writing to the file descriptor of the TUN device.